# python code not returning else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My assignment asks me to make a program that determines whether or not the first number in the list (user input, for demonstration [4,3,2,5,4] [4,3,2,5,1]) is also present in the remainder of the list. So far I got my code to print "yes" if a repetitive number is present, but when there isn't one, it prints a blank line.
Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    numbers = eval(input("enter a list of numbers enclosed in brackets: "))
    item = numbers
    head = item[0]
    list = item[1:]
    yes = False
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(list),1):
        if list[i] == head:
            if (item[i] == head):
                count +=1
            yes = True
            if yes == True:
                print("yes")
        else:
            print("no")

main()
```

Comment: You shouldn't assign item[1:] to list. list is a keyword to instantiate list-objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is easy. If you're looking at index `i` and find the item you can immediately print "yes".

No is hard. You can't simply add an `else` to print "no". To declare the search a failure you need to know that *every* index does not match. You can't just look at one index and then print "no". It's too soon.

To solve this, inside the loop you'll need to track whether you've found the item. When the loop is completely finished, you can then check to see if you found the item anywhere. If you did, print "yes". If not, print "no". The check must be after the loop rather than inside of it.

Comment: am I kind of close though? sorry, Im taking my first python course and I am having some difficulty understanding some of the test coding, what would I need to do(code wise) to test each variable? I thought that was what the count function was for?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do to make your program a little cooler/pythonic/readable.

```
for element in list:
```

This for loop is called for each, it can be explained as: for each element in list, do (your program). The first iteration it'll be the first element, second iteration, it'll be the second item, etc. The current iteration's element can be referred to as the variable 'element'.

Then you can change the if statement, to be:

```
if element == head:
```

I'm not sure why you're comparing 'head' to two different lists of numbers though, as you probably only want to compare to your variable 'list'.

So, if an element does equal head, then the list does contain the first element/head, so yes would equal True. If there is not an element that equals head after going through the whole list, then, yes would remain the initialized value False. So then outside the loop you could check the value of the variable 'yes', which could print 'yes' or 'no' depending on.

Also, to be more clear, I would change 'yes' variable name to something that makes more sense, such as 'is_head_in_list'

Comment: am I at least somewhat close though? This is my first python course and I am still unclear about some things, where do I need to edit my code so that after the loop reads through each number in the list, it can determine if it is false in order to print''no"

Comment: You're fairly close, but doing a few unnecessary things like checking head twice and counting. Those things are making it complicated for no reason, and is not the correct direction to go. Just think of things in steps, such as: 1. split the input into two variables 2. loop through all elements in the list 3. while in the loop, compare head to the element.

Comment: Also, to check the value of 'yes' outside the loop, your if statements should be of equal indentation of the for loop after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about below code:

```
def main():
    head = eval(input("enter a first list of numbers enclosed in brackets: "))
    tail = eval(input("enter a second list of numbers enclosed in brackets: "))

    intersect = set(head) & set(tail)

    print('Yes' if intersect else 'No')
```

and the result of demo:

```
>>> 
>>> main()
enter a first list of numbers enclosed in brackets: [4, 3, 2, 5, 4]
enter a second list of numbers enclosed in brackets: [4, 3, 2, 5, 1]
Yes
>>> main()
enter a first list of numbers enclosed in brackets: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
enter a second list of numbers enclosed in brackets: [6, 7, 8]
No
>>>
```

Here a new code, if can only be one line input:

```
def main():
    numbers = input("enter a list of numbers enclosed in brackets: ")
    posi = numbers.find(']')
    head = eval(numbers[:posi + 1])
    tail = eval(numbers[posi + 1:])

    #head = eval(input("enter a first list of numbers enclosed in brackets: "))
    #tail = eval(input("enter a second list of numbers enclosed in brackets: "))

    intersect = set(head) & set(tail)

    print('Yes' if intersect else 'No')
```

and the demo:

```
>>> 
>>> main()
enter a list of numbers enclosed in brackets: [4,3,2,5,4][4,3,2,5,1]
Yes
>>> main()
enter a list of numbers enclosed in brackets: [1,2,3][4,5,6,7]
No
>>>
```

Hopes, a new code can help you.

Comment: the numbers were just examples, it can be any list of numbers because we have to make the list input from the user :(

Comment: Sure, please see the demo.

Comment: There can only be one line of input, I like that idea though

Comment: If can only be one line of input, you can not use eval.  Because phyton will raise TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.